# How to stop mastubating?

Tags: halal-haram

I am 15 years old i have been stoping myself from masturbating.I always tell myself that its haram its not good for me,its not good for my body but whatever i do i cant stop myself. Like i tell myself this is the last time i am doing but after few days i do it again. I need to focus on my studies and stuff this doesn’t let me. I also fear that Allah may not even forgave me because i have been doing it again and again someone please help.

Comment: Hi, it's better to seek professional help from mental health expert and knowledgeable religious scholar...